# Using android kotlin - problem with random number display + delay

Tags: android, kotlin, random, delay

I am using kotlin in Android Studio.
I am writing a simple program to display a series
of random numbers with a delay of 1 second between
each one.  RandNumText is the name of the on screebn
box.  I have tried the following :-

```
i = 1
while (i < 10) {
    RandNumText.text = ((0..9).random()).toString()
    for (j in 0 until 50000) {}
    i++
}
```

---

```
i = 1
while (i < 10) {
    RandNumText.text = ((0..9).random()).toString()
    Thread.sleep(1000)  // wait for 1 second
    i++
}
```

---

```
i = 1
val handler = Handler()
while (i<10) {
    handler.postDelayed({RandNumText.text = ((0 until 10).random()).toString()}, 1000)
    i++
}
```

---

Each time just one number appears on screen.
What am I doing wrong? Your assistance would
be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first one changes the number 10 times immediately because there is no delay. Counting to 50000 simply wastes a bit of CPU and makes the function take a little longer, but since its called in the main thread, you are not going to see any update of the UI until the function returns. (Also, counting to 50000 should take less than 1-2ms and of course is not an accurate way to keep time.)

The second also does all the changes on the main thread, so you won't see any UI changes because the function doesn't return in between changes. Also, it is blocking the main thread so it can trigger an ANR.

The third one creates ten delayed actions that change the number all after one second, so the changes happen all at once. You could update it to stagger the delays like this:

```
for (i in 0 until 10) {
    handler.postDelayed({RandNumText.text = ((0 until 10).random()).toString()}, 1000 * (i + 1))
}
```

Note however, that these runnables getting passed to the Handler capture the enclosing Activity or Fragment, so they will cause a context leak if the user navigates away. Handler should be stored in a member property and you should call `removeCallbacks()` on it in `onDestroy()`.

If you want this to continue indefinitely, you can make a single Runnable that posts itself:

```
val runnable = object: Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            RandNumText.text = ((0 until 10).random()).toString()
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
        }
    }
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you are generating new number and overriding existing text every time.
Try something like this:

```
RandNumText.text = RandNumText.text + (0..9).random().toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for this very helpful information.  The code below does indeed generate a series of random numbers in the range 0 to 9 and runs continuously.  However, although the delay seems fairly even most of the time, there is an occasional longer pause for some reason.

`enter code here`val handler = Handler()
`enter code here`val runnable = object: Runnable {
`enter code here`    override fun run() {
 `enter code here`       RandNumText.text = ((0..9).random()).toString()
`enter code here`        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
`enter code here`    }
`enter code here`}

`enter code here`handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)

---

This version displays the 10 random numbers in the range 0 to 9, but with very uneven delays in between each one, then leaves the last one on screen.

`enter code here`val handler = Handler()
`enter code here`val runnable = object: Runnable {
`enter code here`    override fun run() {

`enter code here`        for (i in 0 .. 9) {
`enter code here`            RandNumText.text = ((0 .. 9).random()).toString()
`enter code here`            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
`enter code here`        }
`enter code here`    }
`enter code here`}

`enter code here`handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)

I am continuing to try other methods.  I had no idea that such a simple problem as a uniform delay is so difficult to achieve in android kotlin.  Thanks again for your help.